# Authentication failed importing VSTS Git repo into BitBucket

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket

I'm attempting to move my Git repo from VisualStudio.com (VSTS) to BitBucket, and I'm working through the BitBucket UI and choosing to import the repo.  I've supplied the repo url in the following format:

https://MYCOMPANY.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/MYREPO

And I supply my VisualStudio.com login credentials in the fields below, but I'm getting an authentication error as per the screenshot.  Any ideas on what to do?

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a PAT for authentication?

Comment: Since I don't know what that is, maybe not?  When I access the VSTS repo via Visual Studio, I think it uses my Live account.  So I'm reusing those same credentials on this Bitbucket screen.

Comment: Try a PAT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts. Your username would be blank and your password would be a VSTS PAT.

Comment: Awesome, I got it working, but the other way round - token in username and leave password blank.  Can you please post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [personal authentication token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts). Provide the PAT as your username and leave the password blank.

Comment: A personal access token :p